# Create a Clickable Link from a Table made from Database Results

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I'm making a class web-page that allow you to view class details by clicking a link associated with the class. I have a database loaded with classes,enrolled students as well as the assigned professor. Below I have the query in a for each loop creating a table from the results however I want to make the entries urls that direct to that class page. For example: "localhost/class?class_id=cs120". I can't just add a link below and have it parameterized to cs120 as all links would just go there. My understanding of SQLITE3, PHP and HTML is limited, Below is my code for this page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php include("secure.php") ?>
    <html lang= "en">
    <head>
        <title> Class Index </title>
        <meta charset= "utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="class_coverpage.css" />
    </head>

    <?php
      //echo("Hello Retrieving Table");
      $username = $_SESSION['user'];
      //echo 'Hello: ' . $username;
      $classquery = "SELECT DISTINCT Classes.Class_id, Classes.Section_id ,Classes.className, Classes.Subject, Classes.Location FROM Classes,StudentClasses,Students WHERE StudentClasses.Class_id = Classes.Class_id AND StudentClasses.Student_id = Students.Student_id AND StudentClasses.Section_id = Classes.Section_id AND Students.Username = '$username'; ";
      //$teacherquery = "SELECT TeacherClasses.Teacher_id, TeacherClasses.Class_id FROM TeacherClasses";
      //echo("Trimming Query");
      trim($classquery);
      //echo("Stripping Slashes");
      $classquery = stripslashes($classquery);
      //echo("Setting up Query");

      $results = $db->query($classquery);
      if (!$results){
        echo("<h2>Error: The query could not be executed.</h2>");
        $error = $db->lastErrorMsg();
        echo("<p>$error<p>");
        exit;
      }

      echo "<table><tr>";
      echo "<td>Course ID:</td>";
      echo "<td>Section ID:</td>";
      echo "<td>Subject:</td>";
      echo "<td>Location:</td></tr>";
      echo("<tr>");
      for($i=0;$i<$num_cols;$i++){
        $head = $results->columnName($i);
        echo("<th>$head</th>");
      }
      echo ("</tr>");
      // Write rows into table
      $ct = 0;
      while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo ("<tr>");
        foreach($row as $v){
            // I want to Make this section down here create a link hopefully.
            //echo ("<td><a href='class_detail.php?Class_id=$row['id']'> $v </a></td>");
        }
        $ct = $ct + 1;
        echo ("</tr>");
      }
      echo 

("</table>");

?>
```